# AD Users Script correction

Tags: windows, active-directory

Can anyone please correct?

Individual runs of user1 and user 2 running good and appending results

```
(get-aduser -Identity user1 -Properties memberof | select -expand memberof | get-adgroup) |
select Name, groupscope | Out-File -Append c:\scripts\resultsusersad.txt

(get-aduser -Identity user2 -Properties memberof | select -expand memberof | get-adgroup) |
select Name, groupscope | Out-File -Append c:\scripts\resultsusersad.txt
```

When I tried to save both users in a text file and used for loop I am getting error.
This is what I did, given below (Update):

$file = Get-Content -path "c:\scripts\usersad.txt"

foreach ($i in $file)
{
(get-aduser -Identity $($i) -Properties memberof | select -expand memberof | get-adgroup) | select Name, groupscope | Add-Content -Path c:\scripts\resultsusersad.txt
}

Please correct where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try with `$file = Get-Content -Path "c:\scripts\usersad.txt"` instead of your `Get-ChildItem`-line and see if it works better. Also, a piece of advice for any future questions - if you run into a problem and there is an error message, please include the complete error in your original question.

Comment: You are also missing a pipe between `select Name, groupscope` and `Out-File` but perhaps that's just a typo in your question.

Comment: Yes, it was typo. I tried what you suggested, but it is not working. Sorry! There is no need for pulling users from in memory. Bunch of users' member groups have to pull out. That's all.

Comment: I'm merely working with what you've provided. What exactly failed when you read the contents of the file you refer to? I'm pretty sure what's wrong with your script but I have no intention of guessing my way forward - please update your original post to include the full error message(s).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I updated what I did with "update". It ran with no errors now. I saved to user accounts in the file and the output is so with mixed up in the file, as given below:::: @{Name=opsit; groupscope=Universal}
@{Name=ptsdev; groupscope=Global}
@{Name=PTSPolicyGroup; groupscope=Universal}
@{Name=Domain Admins; groupscope=Global}
@{Name=PTS ; groupscope=Universal}
@{Name=ptsit; groupscope=Universal}
@{Name=PTSDEV; groupscope=Global}
@{Name=PTSPolicyGroup; groupscope=Universal}
@{Name=Domain Admins; groupscope=Global}

Comment: Do not worry, I changed the values in the Name etc to save here

Comment: You can use Excel or Google Sheets to clean the data up. you can copy it and use a semi colon as a delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for that ! I just thought of showing the output as it is

Answer (score 0):

I always have trouble with out-file.

What I would do is:

1. Either create a new file in the script, or have one already created and waiting.
2. Variablize the output. Something like

   $Var1 = @(user1 -Properties memberof | select -expand memberof | get-adgroup) | select Name, groupscope)
3. Use 'Add-Content' to write to the file

   Add-Content -Path .\myfile.txt -Value $Var1

I it will append the string as a new line right under the previous one. I use to use a similar method to build CSVs from grabbing data from AD.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! How should I grab individual users from a file? That's where it is throwing error and for loop should be working so that it runs. Any suggestions or corrections?

Comment: lol. That is a much different question. You can use get-content to read the file. If I were you, I would build a CSV with headers and everything, but maybe you don't have to. You are asking about how to build 'Powershell Objects'. Here is an article that will help: https://ridicurious.com/2018/10/15/4-ways-to-create-powershell-objects/

Comment: Why do you need to write it to a file, and then grab info from the file? Why not just get the user list and add it to a variable? I don't see the need for writing to a file and then reading the file. You can't just do it all in memory?

Comment: If you use that method I gave you : $Var1 = @(user1 -Properties memberof | select -expand memberof | get-adgroup) | select Name, groupscope) 

and hit '$Var1.' in PowerShell ISE, it should give you a list of items, that is where you grabbed the info for the -expand and | select. All of the info is there in the variable already. You just need to call it. 
If you have a bunch of info, and you need to build the object, there is a way to do it (linked previously), but AD is giving you a built object. You should just use it...

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to say with all your comments ! LOL ! bunch of users belong to bunch of member groups. each with different job role. Yes, I agree get-content will work. but I check and see it.  Now, it is clear to you why I am saving bunch of users in a file!

Comment: No result with your code: $Var1 = @(myadaccount -Properties memberof | select -expand memberof | get-adgroup) | select Name, groupscope) | Add-Content -Path C:\scripts\myfile.txt -Value $Var1

Comment: you have to play with your command. I didn't put the full command. My suggestion is to build a list in memory. You don't have to write to file. Also you need to understand how to put an array in a variable. That is why you are trying to write to a file I believe.  Try this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: I thought this comment might help: I have used get-content to put lists of users in a variable, and then write a function to query each one. You can then write the output of every user to a file. If you need to do something like that, just put the users in a txt file and add it to a variable. Is that what you are trying to do? Alternatively you could use AD Groups, LDAP Attributes, or lots of other ways to programmatically call the users you want. It may seem easy to build a file at first, but in memory is the way you would want to eventually do it.

Comment: If you are trying to do something complicated, please feel free to reach out to me via linkedin. Link is in my profile.

Comment: Thanks! I think it is fine and no need of Linkedin as of now.

Comment: Here is one more suggestion: I think you should just ask another question. Put down what you are trying to do so someone can help you with the code. I don't think you gave us enough information. Just write a question stating what info you are trying to get, the community will help you. Good luck -

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking to reply and give inputs !!!